# How do I close the Music+Videos application?

Tags: apps, music, 7.x

When I open a song from Music+Videos, I cannot get the player to close unless I reboot my phone.  There has got to be a way to close the app so it doesn't show up on the lock window or whenever I go to adjust the volume.

Here are some pre-emptive responses to popular comments before they are posted here:

- *Why is it even an issue?* > It's merely an annoyance.
- *You don't need to close it.* > But I want to.
- *Download Stop the Music to close the app.* > No.
- *Get an iPhone.* > No.

I look forward to your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to go ahead and say that the only possible way to close the media player on this WP7 is to reboot the phone.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to rid the volume controls of music playing is to play a video. It can be a video you recorded with your camera, or one you've synced to your Videos section. Start and end the video, and the music is no longer in your volume controls. It's a workaround, but it's much quicker than rebooting the phone.

Comment: Brilliant!!! This actually works! Had to create an account on wp.se just to be able to upvote this answer. **Finally** I can get rid of those music player buttons in the lock screen! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I've found that using the back button, or just using other apps like email can be enough to take the media player off the lock screen. It is worth noting that those media controls will appear for other media players as well as the music+videos hub.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to "close" applications in Windows Phone.

While in the app, if you press the "Back" button (to the Left of the Windows Start button" enough times until the app is off the screen, then it is closed. If however you press the "Start" button (button with the Windows logo), the app goes into the background. Because of how Windows Phone operates however, this "background" app is essentially in a paused state which doesnt use any battery power.

There are some built-in apps, such as Music+Video for example, which continue to run even after pressing the "Back" button to exit it. Although, in the case of Music+Video, the app only continue to run if Music is playing (paused/stopped music causes the Music+Video app to go into the "paused" stated as described above).

Answer (score -1):

I've found that if you don't find a way to close the Music app and just leave it in pause, the alarm clock won't sound. This issue is what caused me to search for a way to stop the Music app.

So on your list of some pre-emptive responses.

You don't need to close it. > But I want to.

I will add that you actually do need to. Any app that makes sound will be disabled if you're playing music and leave it in pause mode rather than doing one of the tricks to get the player off the start screen.

Comment: This should be an edit & a comment to the question rather than an answer.

Comment: The alarms have always worked for me when music was paused...